org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'dataChannel':Failed to instantiate No default constructor found
I am upgrading my spring project jars from spring-core-5.3.22 to spring-core-6.1.11 and JDK version to JDK 17. I also upgraded spring integration jar and other dependencies. But I am getting below error after upgrade.
ERROR|main|com.asus.main|.util.Poller:81|Error in Polling org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataChannel': Failed to instantiate No default constructor found
I need help to upgrade my project to the new spring version.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please, share more stack trace for the error and the code where you declare that dataChannel as bean.

Can you show the full stack trace?
